# Read files into variables, using Dir and arrays

Tags: ruby, loops

For an assignment, I'm using the Dir.glob method to read a series of famous speech files, and then perform some basic speech analytics on each one (number of words, number of sentences, etc). I'm able to read the files, but have not figured out how to read each file into a variable, so that I may operate on the variables later.

What I've got is:

```
Dir.glob('/students/~pathname/public_html/speeches/*.txt').each do |speech|
    #code to process the speech.
    lines = File.readlines(speech)
    puts lines
end
```

This prints all the speeches out onto the page as one huge block of text. Can anyone offer some ideas as to why?

What I'd like to do, within that code block, is to read each file into a variable, and then perform operations on each variable such as:

```
Dir.glob('/students/~pathname/public_html/speeches/*.txt').each do |speech|
    #code to process the speech.
    lines = File.readlines(speech)
    text = lines.join
    line_count = lines.size
    sentence_count = text.split(/\.|\?|!/).length
    paragraph_count = text.split(/\n\n/).length
    puts "#{line_count} lines"
    puts "#{sentence_count} sentences"
    puts "#{paragraph_count} paragraphs"
end
```

Any advice or insight would be hugely appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You're probably better off storing the file names in an array (`a << speech` after initializing `a = []`), then process each element of the array separately, the first step being reading the file. You say "process later". If "later" is really "now", then perhaps create a method `def process_file(file_name)...` and replace `lines = File.readlines(speech); puts lines` with `process_file(speech)`.

Comment: So what I'm aiming for is something like:
`a = []
Dir.glob('/students/~pathname/public_html/speeches/*.txt').each do |speech|
f = File.open(speech)
a << f
end`
Am I on the right track?

Comment: I see no point in having files open while you are processing other files. That's why I suggested you just save the filenames in an array. Open each file, process it, close it. Or, more accurately, let Ruby close it. (If you "gulp" the entire file into a string, with `IO.read(file_name)` or `File.read(file_name)`, Ruby will close it after reading the file; if you create a file object--to read line-by-line, say--Ruby will close the file when the file object goes out-of-scope, e.g., when you return from the method that opened the file.) I see you and your brother are close. Does he agree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what wound up working:

```
speeches = []

Dir.glob('/PATH TO DIRECTORY/speeches/*.txt').each do |speech|
    #code to process the speech.
    f = File.readlines(speech)
    speeches << f
end

def process_file(file_name)
    # count the lines
    line_count = file_name.size
    return line_count
end

process_file(speeches[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question:

readLines converts the file into an array of Strings and what you then see is the behaviour of puts with an array of Strings as the argument.

Try `puts lines.inspect` if you would rather see the data as an array.

Also: Have a look at the Ruby console `irb` in case you have not done so already. It is very useful for trying out the kinds of things you are asking about.